# Preventing Form Validation Callback Issues Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

this is my form_validation.php

```
 $config = array(  
         'buy' =>array(
                       array(
                              'field'   => 'id',
                              'label'   => 'Item',
                              'rules'   => 'trim|required'
                            ),
                       array(
                              'field'   => 'qty',
                              'label'   => 'Quantity',
                              'rules'   => 'trim|greater_than[0]|callback_validate_qty'
                            )
                     )
                );
```

My Controller to load form validation :

```
$this->load->library('form_validation');
```

Function validate_qty($qty)

```
$item_id = $this->input->post('id');
$total_item= $this->item_model->getTotalItem($item_id);
if ($qty >= $total_item) {
    $this->form_validation->set_message('validate_qty', 'Cant Buy More than maximum stock!');
    return FALSE;
    }
```

this validation is work perfectly, but someone has got throught it, he buy more than maximum stock.. 
How to prevent this? I don't know how he does that, but it looks like the validation didn't work for him. When I tested, it works perfectly, I don't know what's wrong with it, maybe he uses software or anything? is there any solution? Thanks

Comment: The third snippet seems to have a syntax error. Are you sure it works?

Comment: already edit it here, thanks Carlos, the message is different from my project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume if you have 30 stock in your hand and you want to get all 30 stocks out. But according to your `if` condition (**`if ($qty >= $total_item) {`**) it throws error.

**Fix 1**

- if should be `>` (`if ($qty > $total_item) {`).

**Fix 2**

Typo - in your callback function you've used two underscores `_`. Get rid of one

```
callback__validate_qty
        ^^
```

Read more about [codeigniter.com - Callbacks](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks-your-own-validation-methods)

Comment: thanks for ur feedback Abdulla, for fix 2 it's not a typo, my function name is _validate_qty, I always use underscores for callback name, thanks

Comment: @jeffianjuniardy two underscores? if so that isn't allowed by ci. reduce to `_` in the param and definition

Comment: ah really, Idk about it, thanks @alex, I will change it

Answer (score 1):

i think your code is correct.

i have one doubt on that code.
check the variable you used in if condition is correct or not ($qty). becuase you not show the full code.i don't known how that variable comes.

Also change the code like if and else condition.

```
if ($qty >= $total_item) {
 $this->form_validation->set_message('validate_qty', 'Cant Buy More than maximum stock!');
 return false;
} else {
 return true;
}
```